# C# Entity Framework resources and assembly resolve (appdomain)

Tags: c#, assemblyresolve

I am facing a problem that I can't seem to explain what is going on.

It is likely that if I use `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event in my DLL(C#) and I use Entity Framework, somehow, I see it tries to load the following resource file:

```
EntityFramework.resources, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=fr-FR, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

and after

```
EntityFramework.resources, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I can't figure out where they could reside and neither if they exist somewhere.
I can't find any discussion or Microsoft site talking about that.

For sure, everything works well if I return null in my event for that resources as state in Microsoft's documentation on `AssemblyResolve` event but the problem is that I would like to be able to not return null because there is another DLL (built before .NET 4) that is done by an external company and use in the same application than my DLL that will try to load the assembly resource file and throw an exception which makes the application crash.

For that reason, I,m trying to understand how to handle that particular case and avoid returning null.

Does someone have any explanation why Entity Framework would try to load those resources files and if there is a way to handle this without returning null from `aassemblyresolve`?

Comment: Thank you @marc_s for the corrections done on my post, really more clear that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The solution is simple.

When asked for `EntityFramework.resources`, simply return the "already" loaded `EntityFramework` instance from the current `AppDomain` instead of using `LoadFrom/Load/LoadFile` methods.

Hope this helps someone in the future.